# Solve analytically PDE rational functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I am struggling to find a function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{-x^2}{(1-x-y)^2} \\
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{-y^2}{(1-x-y)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such function exists since ${\displaystyle {\partial \over \partial y} \frac{-x^2}{(1-x-y)^2}  \neq {\partial \over \partial x} \frac{-y^2}{(1-x-y)^2}}$ but one always has ${\displaystyle {\partial \over \partial y} {\partial \phi \over \partial x} = {\partial \over \partial x} {\partial \phi \over \partial y}}$ by the equality of mixed partials.

Comment: You assume $\varphi$ at least of class $\mathbb{C}^2$ ? 
What if I ask less regularity for $\varphi$ ?

Comment: The mixed partials are unequal whenever $y \neq x$, so if such an example exists it would have to not be $C^2$ at each point $(x,y)$ where $y \neq x$. I do not think this would be easy to construct if it exists.

Comment: ok, and this doesn't contradict the implicit function theorem (see my edit) ?

Comment: No, I don't think you're using the implicit function theorem correctly there. In the current form the function is linear.